# compare l/min output of CO2 pressure reducer to bar (compressed air)

Tags: compressed-air, compressed-gases

I have a pressure reducer calibrated for Argon and CO$_2$ output. If I connected it to a gas tank with compressed air, how can I convert the output information "liters of Argon / CO$_2$ per minute" to "pressure of compressed air in bar"?

Answer (score 1):

The units of "liters of Argon / CO2 per minute" is a flow rate (volume delivered in time) and is not equivalent to "pressure of compressed air in Bar" which is pressure (force / area).

Would you get what you need if you connected a pressure gauge to the output side?

Comment: yes, that would work, but as I do not intent to change the output pressure very often I was just curious if I can't convert those two values. It's still a manometer, even though it displays a flow rate, so there should be a way to calculate it, shouldn't it?

Comment: @muffel Are you sure? Many manual gas flow meters use a little ball that floats on the passing gas and the position of the ball is how the flow rate is read. They resemble a manometer, but they are definitely NOT a manometer. There's no way to use this as a pressure gage. Of course a picture would help.